# Custom bibliography inclusions

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

I have a bib file generated by Zotero (can become biblatex if needed) and I use natbib bibliographies through the package revtex4 (I could also use aastex if needed). Zotero kindly outputs every single detail (DOI, URL and abstracts etc).

I need the bibliography entries to include only the names, year and journal like so: `Abadi M. G., Moore B., Bower R. G., 1999, MNRAS, 308,
947` (see http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0583)

I've also come across true/false conditions of properties like author, doi, url etc from [Bibliography with only initials of names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128810/bibliography-with-only-initials-of-names).

There must be a simple way just to turn off features like DOI and URL!

Thanks

Here's MWE:

```
\documentclass[preprint2]{aastex}   
% \usepackage[authoryear,round,comma]{natbib}
% \usepackage[%
%     style=numeric-comp,sorting=none,
%     sortcites=true,doi=false,url=false,
%     firstinits=true,hyperref]{biblatex}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,round,comma}
\begin{document}
    hello \citep{christlein_can_2004}


\bibliography{Zotero}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Using `biblatex`, you can use the option `isbn=false` (or `url`, `doi` or `eprint`), to be given in the preamble package option. If there are other fields you'd like to suppress, you can use the commands

```
\AtEveryCitekey{{\clearfield{month}}
\AtEveryBibitem{{\clearfield{note}}
```

to remove the chosen fields from citations (useful for the verbose citation styles) and from the bibliography, respectively.