# How to overwrite biblatex options for some references?

Tags: biblatex

Using biblatex, with the option to use initials for first name (as found in the question: [Bibliography with only initials of names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128810/bibliography-with-only-initials-of-names/128823)):

```
\usepackage[
    giveninits=true,
    style=numeric-comp,
    backend=biber
]{biblatex}
```

Is there a way to ignore this option for SOME references?

i.e. I want most of my references to have initals and surnames, but I wan't a couple references to have full names. Is this possible? (i.e. when an author is an organisation)

Comment: The option `giveninits` is a preamble option in itself, so you should expect it to have global effects. But there might be ways to have full names for some entries. If you provide a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) you will have a better chance of receiving a good answer.

Comment: I found that double curly braces worked `{{Some Organisation}}`

Comment: Your problems were restricted to corporate authors then? If so, that's the appropriate approach.

Comment: See also [Using a 'corporate author' in the “author” field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864)