# use only initials for author name in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, citing, multiple-citations

```
\usepackage[style=numeric,language=english, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
```

```
@article{first,
  author =       "Michelle Carney and   Barron Webster and Irene Alvarado and Kyle Phillips and Noura Howell and Jordan Griffith and Jonas Jongejan and Amit Pitaru",
  title =        "{Article Name}",
  journal =      "CHI EA '20: Extended Abstracts of the 2020 CHI Conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems",
  year =         "2020",
  DOI =          "https://doi.org/"
}
```

Currently, my output is something like this:

```
 Michelle Carney, Barron Webster, Irene Alvarado, Kyle Phillips, Noura Howell, Jor-dan Griffith
```

but I want to shorten it such that names are like
`Michelle C., Barron W, Irene A,` etc.

As mentioned here,
[Bibliography with only initials of names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128810/bibliography-with-only-initials-of-names)
I tried this, `giveninits=true`but it just reduces my reference to

```
 Michelle Carney et al.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Let me make sure I understand your formatting requirements: You want to show the full given names and truncate the surnames. Is this right?

Comment: From the answer below, I realize that it's more common to abbreviate the first names instead of the surnames. So I should stick to that. @Mico

Answer (score 1):

### Update

If you want to abbreviate given names, use the `giveninits` option (which in older versions of `biblatex` was called `firstinits`). That option does not influence `maxnames` and friends, so has no influence on whether or not a list of names is shortened with "et al.".

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, maxbibnames=99, giveninits]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum,aksin}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Ö. Aksın, H. Türkmen, L. Artok, B. Çetinkaya, C. Ni, O. Büyükgüngör and E. Özkal.]

---

It is quite unusual to abbreviate the family/last names of people in the bibliography, but Biber already provides abbreviated family names, we just have to use them.

For initials of given names there is a simple option called `giveninits` and while a similar option exists for the family name it doesn't do anything with the standard styles. So here we just define a new name format and use that.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameFormat{given-f}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:given-family}
    {\namepartfamilyi}
    {\namepartgiven}
    {\namepartprefixi}
    {\namepartsuffix}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{given-f}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum,aksin}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Emma S. and Ulf R.]

Comment: If abbreviating first names is more common then I should also stick to that. However, I already tried ```giveninits=true``` with the usepackage option but it does not work as expected. Instead, it changes the remaining names to 'et all'

Comment: @x89 The option `giveninits` has no effect on list truncation with 'et al.'. Have a look at the updated answer to see an example with many names that is not truncated. If you get truncation even though you set `maxnames` to a high value, please provide a complete example document that reproduces the unexpected behaviour.